# Can't install Tomcat 7 in Windows Silently using Config file

Tags: java, tomcat, automation, silent-installer

I'am using Windows environment and trying to automate apache tomcat (apache-tomcat-7.0.42. ex) install (silent install) in my D Drive using a batch file (. bat).

My JDK and JRE is also installed in My D Drive, I follow the steps in the Tomcat setup:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html

So I'am trying to use a config file (. ini) with all my settings in (TomcatPortHttp, ...) using /c=MyFile.ini switch but nothing happened

Can anyone help me with an example of tomcat config file (ini or cfg..).

Thanks.

Comment: Does not matter where JDK or JRE is located on the disk, but matters the value of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Do you use Windows installer? Why the default config of the installer is not ok?

Comment: If you are reading the online documentation, you have to use the up-to-date version of Tomcat. That is 7.0.104 as of now. (If you really need a 7 years old version (7.0.42), the docs can be downloaded from an archive. I do not remember how silent install worked back then and whether it was implemented at all.)